# react-router Link not working with nested Route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

**EDIT: After many tests, I finally have the sad news that what is actually breaking the router is the "tree" framework that is used in my sidebar menu. When I do not use the *$('data-widget="tree"').tree({...* the router works perfectly. I'm trying to figure out how to solve this issue by my self for now.**

I'm basically implementing this simple example with login and a "Master Page" with a side-menu and a content, so I can learn more about the new version of react-router. When I "finished" the Login(frontend and backend), the next part was the creation of the menu based on the user permissions. Then I realized that that the tag Link from "react-router-dom" wasn't working. I tried many solutions/suggestions that I found online and none of them were effective. In the end, I noticed that when I put a Link on the Login.jsx it worked. The error only appeared for the links referring to the nested Routes.

Images:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpsyZ.jpg (Login screen with a test Link that works)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/e63KF.jpg (The "main" screen with the Links of the menu that doens't work)

Here's the dependencies that I'm using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "admin-lte": "^2.4.3",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  }
```

And here's my "index.js":

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

import Login from './telas/Login'
import MainPage from './telas/MainPage'

import Home from './telas/Home'
import Tela1 from './telas/Tela1'
import Tela2 from './telas/Tela2'

import Telas from './telas/Telas'
import ControleAcessos from './telas/ControleAcessos'
import ControleUsuarios from './telas/ControleUsuarios'

import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker'

const Main = () => (
    <MainPage>
        <Route>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/main/home' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/main/tela1' component={Tela1} />
                <Route path='/main/tela2' component={Tela2} />
                <Route path='/main/controle_acessos' component={ControleAcessos} />
                <Route path='/main/controle_usuarios' component={ControleUsuarios} />
                <Route path='/main/telas' component={Telas} />
            </Switch>
        </Route>
    </MainPage>
)

const Inicial = () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/main' component={Main} />
    </Switch>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Inicial />
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'))

registerServiceWorker()
```

Answer (score 0):

The path provided should be as follows

```
const Main = () => (
    <MainPage>
        <Route path='/main'>            
                <Route path='home' component={Home} />
                <Route path='tela1' component={Tela1} />
                <Route path='tela2' component={Tela2} />
                <Route path='controle_acessos' component={ControleAcessos} />
                <Route path='controle_usuarios' component={ControleUsuarios} />
                <Route path='telas' component={Telas} />             
        </Route>
    </MainPage>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `Main` component should look like this:

```js
const Main = () => (
    <MainPage>
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/main/home' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/main/tela1' component={Tela1} />
            <Route path='/main/tela2' component={Tela2} />
            <Route path='/main/controle_acessos' component={ControleAcessos} />
            <Route path='/main/controle_usuarios' component={ControleUsuarios} />
            <Route path='/main/telas' component={Telas} />
        </Switch>
    </MainPage>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to present the basic idea that react recommends for nested routes.
For nested routes to be working in react we put the nested routes in nested component itself.

#### Wrong

```
<Route path='/lists' component={Lists}>
  <Route path='/lists/:listId' component={List} />
</Route>
```

#### Correct

```
<Route path='/lists' component={Lists} />
```

and

```
const Lists = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Lists</h2>
    <Link to={`${match.url}/exampleListId`}>
      Example list
    </Link>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/:listId`} component={List}/>
  </div>
)
```

Here is what the [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) says about this.